# Orchard CMS continues executing request after permanent redirect from IActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, action-filter

We have a website that uses Orchard CMS and we've written a "RedirectFilter" to do permanent redirects on legacy URLs (aliases that don't match the `AutoroutePart` pattern for the relevant Content Item).

The filter implements `IActionFilter` and inherits `FilterProvider`. It works fine and when it does a redirect it calls the following method in `OnActionExecuting`:

`filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectPermanent(targetPath, true);`

According to the documentation the second parameter suggests that a `ThreadAbortException` will be thrown to abort the current request. However, the request is still processed for the legacy URL, I know this because the Part Drivers still execute for *both* the legacy and new URLs.

How can I abort the request from the filter without Orchard continuing to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just worked this out. Need to use this instead:

`filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(targetPath, true);`

I'm guessing you can't call `RedirectPermenant` inside a filter.