# Store global token in Cache

Tags: c#, permissions, token, orchardcms, authorizationservices

I have a module which in the `AuthorizationServiceEventHandler` `Checking` or `Complete` Events i'm sending a request to an external API which gives me some **instructions** like what modules should be enabled/displayed to the user .

The appraoch i want to follow is storing this instructions somewhere probably on the cache and then whenever a *Service module Exposed* being requested by the user (through a controller ) the module will check the instructions using the `CacheManager` .

the problem with the standard Permissions answered by [ViRuSTriNiTy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400301/orchard-themed-attribute-outside-controllers) is the instructions or permissions may changes depending on other permission (like if permission A is granted the permission C is also granted ) and this instructions are decided by an external API and will be changing all the time .

i'm trying for days to find a proper way or approach to follow to achieve this .

This Illustrate what my module will be doing . 
[image: ViRuSTriNiTy]

So the API will not be giving specifically that `module 1` and `module 3` should be enabled, it will only gives you instructions .
**House** should be replaced by **hospital**

EDIT 1: 
what i meant by house should be  hopistal in the picture Api responds with Hopistal instead of house i just messed it up .

EDIT 2: 
what i want to achieve is a module which control what modules should be available to a specific user, every user has different characteristics which the API will examine and decide what values will be returned to the module , and the module then depending on those instructions will determine which modules will be available to the user .

E.g a user which has no **house** will not use the `House module` like permissions the module will returns an Unauthorized httpcode with a styled message : You have no house .

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are asking. Can you give a concrete example on how the external API sends the instruction and how a module would check a instruction? Please edit your question when possible.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy it will be sending a json format which i will be parsing on the module

Comment: @Kresi That's not an example. With example i mean something like your last sentence`House should be replaced by hospital` but with some context.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I Edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define some permissions first.

Example:

Permission A in Module `House`: `CanAccess`

Permission B in Module `Children`: `CanAccess`

Now in your handler you can get the module from the permission and then ask the API to return the appropriate value.

Permission `House.CanAccess` > Module `House` -> ExternalAPI.CanAccess(`House`) -> return from handler as needed

Comment: this may works but will means to apply this on every module that currently exist and all modules which will comes later . i'm really trying to find a way to separate this in a separate module.

Comment: Maybe you should use something like `IRequestFilter` or `IActionFilter` to catch requests globally and then redirect as needed? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16561962/3936440

Comment: It feels like you may want to do what @ViRuSTriNiTy suggests, and add to that an override of both RolesBasedAuthorizationService and Permission. Your own permissions would be processed in your service as API calls, while more conventional Orchard permissions could still use the RolesBasedAuthorizationService that is normally used (provided you call base.Method in method overrides)

Comment: Basically, you would have that service override in your ModuleX from the picture in the question.